# Dynamic naming of variable in JavaScript in for loop

Tags: javascript

I have a requirement where in I have to populate these variables using for loop in JavaScript 
digitalData.option1.name1
digitalData.option2.name2  so on.....
I tried below code

```
var i=1;
for(some conditions){
digitalData.this["option"+i].this["option"+i] = value;
i++;
}
```

But it is showing syntax error and I also tried this
Window["digitalData.option+i+.name+i"]
But digitaData is not getting populated

Comment: Remove `this` and `.` in this line `digitalData.this["option"+i].this["option"+i]`

Comment: @SagarJajoriya Unfortunately it's not that *easy* as that will result in `cannot set property name0 of undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```js
var digitalData = digitalData || {}

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  digitalData["option"+i] = digitalData["option"+i] || {}
  digitalData["option"+i]["name"+i] = i
}

console.log(digitalData)
```

You need to do the setting in two steps, otherwise you get a `cannot set property name0 of undefined` error.

Comment: I was wondering what if we had something like digitalData.pageInfo.marketing.option1.name1???..will this also follow same steps???

Comment: Be careful if some of those properties already exist - you probably don't want to overwrite these then using `= {}`. I'll update my answer to make it safer.

Comment: Please ask a new question.